# merging (git) origin to my current local working branch

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I am new to git and I would like clarification on something I have been doing last few days when using git but I am not quite sure it is correct way of doing it.

So, we have `origin` (remote repository) and `master` (local branch of that repository)

Here is how I start work:

1. `git fetch origin` //gets the latest code from `origin` (or `remote`)
2. `git merge origin/master` // merges that latest code into local `master`
3. then I create new branch off master `git checkout -b newbranch`
4. now I work on `newbranch` for 2-3 days and I realize, I should refresh my `newbranch` since others might have added some new code (I believe, term is called "reverse integrating")

How do I do this last step?

I believe if I do `git fetch origin/git merge origin/master`, that will refresh (or reverse integrate) `master` only.

If I do `git fetch origin/git merge origin/newbranch`, that wont work, I get message like '`merge: origin/newbranch- not something we can merge`'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

newbranch should be current branch, to make sure you can checkout it, then you get updated from you repo using fetch and then merge newbranch with master

About checkout: branch, with which you're currently working is already checkout. To switch to another branch you need checkout it. If already you're working with branch you don't need checkout.

```
git checkout newbranch
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

instead merge you can use rebase, in this case last line should be replaced

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Merge and rebase just update you branch with information from other branch. Merge get commits from master and add them to your branch. Rebase did the same by a little different way. See [Merging vs. Rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing). For now just forget about rebase, just do merge.

Comment: would you mind elaborating please, I am new to git.  Above in my example, I already created newbranch, not sure why to call git checkout or rebase?

Comment: @pixel, added some text

Comment: Would you mind explaining what these 2 lines do like I am 2yrs old?  (checkout, and rebase).  Thanks

Comment: branch, with which you're currently working is checkout. To switch to another branch you need checkout it. If already you're working with branch you don't need checkout.

Comment: merge and rebase just update you branch with information from other branch. Merge get commits from master and add them to your branch. Rebase did the same by a little different way. See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing For now just forget about rebase, just do merge

Comment: The code won't work as given: `git fetch` does not update `master` at all, so `git merge master` will use an outdated version of `master`. The correct approach is `git checkout master ; git fetch ; git merge ; git checkout newbranch ; git merge master`.

Comment: @cmaster, `git fetch` fetch all branches

Comment: @Alexan It fetches, but it does not merge. `master` still points at exactly the same commit as it did before the `git fetch`. If you want to actually update a branch, you must either do so explicitly with `git merge` or use `git pull`. `git fetch` alone does not have any effect on any branches.

Comment: @cmaster, I think you're right. In this case we can use `git merge origin/master`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do:

1. `git stash`  #store your changes of your local newbranch in a stack
2. `git pull --rebase origin/master` #take the origin latest change in local   newbranch
3. `git stash pop` #pop the changes in step1 that is stored in stack
4. if there is a conflict, you should resolve confict, and then continue to work until you push all of your changes in origin.

Comment: @Maciej Jureczko,Thanks for your editing, This is my first time to answer question in stackoverflow, and I don't know how to edit the format.

Comment: It's ok, that's what reviewers are for :) Make sure you read the help sections on asking and answering though: https://stackoverflow.com/help Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
git pull --rebase origin <branch name>
```

It will fetch all commits of that branch and put your commit on top of that.

Comment: would you mind elaborating using my example above please, I am new to git?

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin newbranch` 
where the newbranch has some new commits on repo.

Comment: I haven't done any 'add' or 'commit' on newbranch.  Do I have to do that first, before merging?  Is that the reason why my merge above fails?

Comment: Aah , Got it. ` stash` is a great feature of git.

@pixel If you didn't finish the task  and want to do more , means you are in middle of task and want to fetch latest commits of repo - then run following commands - 
`git add --all ` .  -> Add all files 
`git stash` .  -> it will put your changes in a bucket 
`git pull --rebase origin newbranch` . -> take latest changes of branch
`git stash apply` . -> pop up changes 
continue to your task.

Comment: I am confused.  All I want to do is refresh my 'newbranch' as explained in the question above.  So, my current branch is 'newbranch' and I have some changes that I did not 'add' nor 'commit'.  What are the steps to simply refresh 'newbranch'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154373/discussion-between-manish-pathak-and-pixel).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this sequence:

```
git fetch    # get all new upstream commits

# bring master up to date
git checkout master
git merge    # equivalent to `git merge origin/master`

# bring newbranch up to date
git checkout newbranch
git merge master
```

The first merge will usually result in a fast-forward, so no merge conflicts there. I would strongly advise against mindless use of any solution that uses `rebase`: This would rewrite history, and [`git` does not like lies.](http://paul.stadig.name/2010/12/thou-shalt-not-lie-git-rebase-ammend.html)

Since `git pull` is the same as `git fetch ; git merge`, you can also do this:

```
# bring master up to date
git checkout master
git pull

# bring newbranch up to date
git checkout newbranch
git merge master
```

This saves you exactly one line of typing.